# Use the same keyboard shortcuts across all window managers? (RIP bbkeys)

Tags: shortcut-keys, window-manager, window-management

By configuring and running `bbkeys` I was able to [define all my favourite keyboard shortcuts](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/master/.bbkeysrc) for manipulating windows and starting applications in one place, and then use them from any window manager.  (Albeit only generic actions, not those strongly integrated with the WM.)

But now bbkeys is no longer packaged for Ubuntu.  So I have to [define](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/master/.config/compiz/compizconfig/Default.ini) [separate](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/master/.fluxbox/keys) [configurations](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/master/.config/openbox/lxde-rc.xml) for each [window manager](https://github.com/joeytwiddle/rc_files/blob/master/GNUstep/Defaults/WindowMaker).

Is there any alternative to bbkeys?

Or is there any software that can manage configuration for multiple window managers all in one place?

Answer (score 1):

One very convenient alternative that you can use is  . . .  **drum-roll** . . .  `unity-settings-daemon` and/or `gnome-settings-daemon` if you have gnome installed. Personally, I use `blackbox` and `openbox` time to time. But I have quite a few convenient shortcuts set in Unity's settings, which some of them are linked to scripts. By setting `gnome-settings-daemon` to autostart , I get those back in other environments.  Big kicker is that it's a native tool to Ubuntu, it comes with `unity-settings-daemon` or if you have `gnome` shell , it comes with `gnome-settings-daemon`

In addition, you can use `gsettings` to change settings, such as background picture , or a big one for me - input language.